# How to programmatically stop a screen video recorder from recording an Android app

Tags: android

I don't want anyone to use a screen recording app on their Android phone to VIDEO record my app's screen. I know screen capture can be prevented, but what about video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding FLAG_SECURE into your Activity You can secure screen capturing functionality

```
getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

write above `setContenView();`

from [documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#ScreenCapture)

> Android 5.0 lets you add screen capturing and screen sharing
>   capabilities to your app with the new android.media.projection APIs.
>   This functionality is useful, for example, if you want to enable
>   screen sharing in a video conferencing app.
>
> The new createVirtualDisplay() method allows your app to capture the
>   contents of the main screen (the default display) into a Surface
>   object, which your app can then send across the network. The API only
>   **allows capturing non-secure screen content**, and not system audio. To
>   begin screen capturing, your app must first request the user’s
>   permission by launching a screen capture dialog using an Intent
>   obtained through the createScreenCaptureIntent() method.

and Also from this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SECURE) says

> Window flag: treat the content of the window as secure, **preventing it
>   from appearing in screenshots or from being viewed on non-secure
>   displays**.

**NB**
If you are using `SurefaceView` with media player then use `SurfaceView.setSecure(true)`, then your video will be secured from any other apps.